# how to convert pointers to integers and vise versa?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following piece of code:

```
    typedef Module * Ptr;
producer(Ptr net)
    Ptr Node;
    Node = net;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    produce(q,(uint64_t)Node);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Here produce is a library:
produce(Queue q, uint64_t value)

Then I have the consumer's code:

```
 consumer()
    Ptr Node;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(!canConsume(q))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
    }
    Node = (Ptr)consume(q);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

However, when I try to printout the value of modNode in both functions. While Node in the producer functions appears to be the address, the Node in the consumer function appears to be 0. I think I somehow mess up with the conversion between pointers and integers, because this code works fine with passing integers. My question is how should I convert pointer to uint64_t?

Comment: What's `q`? Did you write `consume` and `produce` yourself? Are you sure there are no bugs in `consume` or `produce`?

Comment: Problem may be that you don't know the actual pointer size on every platform you'll build on. So try to use [`(u)intptr_t`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h#Integers_wide_enough_to_hold_pointers) whenever you can.

Comment: Hard to tell from your post, but as Node is 0 when you test it and 0 is generally the value equivalent of a NULL pointer in C, I'd suspect that at some stage your consume() function is returning a NULL.  Possibly the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a pointer to `uint64_t`, use the cast operator:

```
(uint64_t)ptr
```

When printing pointers with `printf`, you want to use the `%p` formatting specifier:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);
```

Don't forget to convert `ptr` to `void*` unless `ptr` is either `void*` or `char*` or a qualified variant of these.

Comment: AFAICT, `printf("%p\n",ptr)` is fine [i.e. no cast needed] even with `-Wall` and when `ptr` is a struct pointer

Comment: One should not use a different integer type to convert a pointer than `(u)intptr_t`. Any other integer does not guarantee the pointer value survives unchanged.

Comment: @CraigEstey: For a variadic function you have to cast the pointer. This is the only exception from the rule to never cast a pointer to/from `void *` in C. If the compiler does not warn is not a guarantee you don't have a problem (wish it was that easy).

Comment: @Olaf A pointer has the same size [4/8] regardless of type.  So, printf works.  That is, type cast doesn't [seem to] matter.  (e.g.) `typedef void (*vfnc_p)(int,...)` is fine.  So, maybe you're thinking about something else?  Can you post a code frag or a link in a comment here?

Comment: @CraigEstey Undefined Behaviour may “work” just fine when you try it. However, it's not guaranteed to do what you think. POSIX guarantees what you think, but in general, you need that cast.

Comment: @FUZxxl How is this UB?  As I asked Olaf, can you provide a code frag or link to illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: @CraigEstey On some platforms (e.g. some word-oriented architectures), a pointer to `char` has a different representation than a pointer to `int`. Passing a pointer to `int` to a variable argument that expects a pointer to `char` would cause a reinterpretation of the different representation, yielding undefined behaviour.

Comment: @FUZxxl Got an arch in mind?  I'm familiar with pdp-8, pdp-10, pdp-11, vax, DG nova/eclipse, Prime [even segmented], HP 2100a, IBM/370, z80 et. al., mc680x0, 6502, PIC18F, mips, arm, microblaze, nios, sparc, itanium, some TI DSPs, numerous microcontrollers [some I've created because I'm a computer engineer], 8088/8086, 80186, 80286, x86.  Unless the width of the pointer is different [regardless of content], it will work with printf %p.  Here, you're just trying to dump the hex value of the pointer--no interpretation of what the value may mean or how it's dereferenced properly

Comment: @CraigEstey: Iff the pointers are identical, the cast will not generate any code. If not, you are on the safe (and standard-compliant) side. Just to add that an implementation might choose to use different pointers/ranges for different data-types, e.g. to extend the addressing range or use features of the hardware. There are some custom CPUs/DSPs in FPGAs which exhibit such features,very well. Great you know so many architectures (I will not join a p**ing contest). May I suggest you read the C standard, too?